# if statement not evaluating to false? Program giving strange output. Why?

Tags: c++

I have to write a program that receives unsigned inputs and places them in an array of unsigned values. If a non-unsigned value is entered, I call a function called "die" to output an error message, and terminate the program. Here is the code I have written for my input function:

```
void input(unsigned a[], unsigned elements){

    cout << "Enter unsigned numbers one at a time, each followed by enter." << endl;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < elements;i++){
        cout << "[" << i << "]: ";      // outputs each index as user is inputting
        cin >> a[i];

        if ( sizeof(a[i]) != sizeof(unsigned) || a[i]<0 ){
        die("Invalid input. Program will now exit.");
        }   
    }
}
```

I've checked and the die function performs its job properly on its own. Here is the output this code yields when a char is entered:

```
Enter unsigned numbers one at a time, each followed by enter.
[0]: d
[1]: [2]: [3]: [4]: [5]: [6]: [7]: [8]: [9]: Press any key to continue . . .
```

As you can see, the die function is never successfully called because the if statement preceding it does not evaluate to be false. Furthermore, I'm not sure why my program shows whitespace for the rest of the values in the array. **How could I rewrite the if statement to call the die function whenever the input received is not an unsigned?**

Comment: Clang and GCC: *warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false*

Comment: @chris Ah, I see why my if statement doesn't work now, but how could I test for invalid inputs? I've been thinking about it and I'm totally lost.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your `if()` expression can never be mathematically evaluated as true.

Let's take a look:

```
if ( sizeof(a[i]) != sizeof(unsigned) || a[i]<0 ){
```

Let's break this down into two parts. Part 1:

`a[i]` is an `unsigned`. Therefore

```
sizeof(unsigned) != sizeof(unsigned)
```

will always be false.

Part 2. And because `a[i]` is unsigned, it can never be negative, therefore

```
a[i] < 0
```

will also always be false.

And that's what your `die`() will never execute.

Comment: I see why it doesn't work currently, but how could one test for invalid input in this case, then? How do I exclude anything other than unsigneds?

Comment: @MV94, You can, and should, verify that input succeeds: `if (cin >> a[i])`

Comment: @chris you can't.. http://ideone.com/P21f9Z It will automatically wrap around negative numbers to fit into the unsigned type. Doesn't seem to fail when using floats either.. @OP; you already print out "Please enter unsigned numbers".. If your user is stupid enough to try something else then that's their fault. Otherwise you might have to input into a string and do a range check on that instead which will be much harder.

Comment: @Brandon, I thought the OP meant something like entering "abc", but that's my bad. As for non-integers, take 2.5 as an example. It will extract just the 2 because `.` isn't a valid character. However, it still extracted something, so that counts as success. What's left is `.5` for the next extraction.

Comment: One useful tool in my bag-of-tricks, to easily check for bad input is to store the input in a std::string first, then convert it to an unsigned, or an equivalent, using std::istringstream, then convert the unsigned value back into a std::string using std::ostringstream, then compare the two strings. If they're different, then the input was bad. This catches not only bad input, but situations such as overflow, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Why the presented code doesn't work has been answered previously, I will try to react on MV94's comment how to solve this:

Instead of reading directly into the unsigned int variable, read to signed variable of a bigger size than unsigned int and perform the check before assigning into the a[i]. Exact type choice depends on your architecture (you can try `intmax_t` from `<cstdint>`). Of course this will only again handle numbers within some range, if user enters number big enough to exceed your signed type, you have similar problem. As someone mentioned before, check that your input conversion succeeded.